# Rotate matrix built from 1d array

Tags: python, matrix

Hello I have a sorted list `['a','b','c','d','e','f']` that is currently displayed on the front end as the matrix

`['a','c','e'],
 ['b,'d','f'],`

When it should be

`['a','b','c'],
 ['d,'e','f'],`

Unfortunately I'm not able to modify the front end to display the object horizontally so I would like to be able to rearrange the 1d array into another 1d array with the correct order `['a','d','b','e','c',f']`.

I conceptually know how it could be done by converting the 1d array into a 2d array, then rotating the matrix, then converting the 2d array back into a 1d array. However I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way/faster general algorithm for achieving this.

Comment: I'm unclear as to the data structure.  What package are you using that supports arrays and matrices?  Give us some trivial set-up code to show what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With `numpy`

I believe the most efficient, considering that you are talking about a GUI and GUI tend to change in size, would be to use `numpy` to implement your own proposal:

```
a = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
n = len(a)
a.reshape(2, int(n)/2).T.reshape(1,n)
```

The output is:

```
array([['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
```

### Speed comparison

#### Using slicing

Using the solution from the answer of [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim):

```
%timeit [*L[0::3], *L[1::3], *L[2::3]]
>>> 559 ns ± 18 ns per loop
```

#### Using Numpy, with conversion to and back

```
%timeit np.array(L).reshape(2,3).T.reshape(1,6).tolist()
>>> 5.01 µs ± 257 ns per loop
```

#### Using Numpy, without conversions

```
a = np.array(L)
%timeit L.reshape(2,3).T.reshape(1,6)
>>> 1.58 µs ± 84.1 ns per loop
```

#### Using slicing with list comprehension

```
n = int(len(L)/2)
%timeit [j for i in range(n) for j in L[i::n]]
>>> 1.31 µs ± 73.3 ns
```

#### Conclusions

It seems that, for constant sizes, [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) answer with slicing is best, followed by slicing with list comprehension when the size is not known beforehand.

Comment: Do you know how I would account for the case where `a = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e'])`. Is there some way to fill with empty temporary values so that it is able to resize?

Comment: Adding a padding of empty string would be feasible? Like, `if len(a)%2!=0: a.append('')`?

Answer (score 2):

Stride it with slices:

```
>>> L = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> [*L[0::3], *L[1::3], *L[2::3]]
['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f']
```

Consider using numpy if you need to generalise this to arbitrary dimensions:

```
>>> np.array(L).reshape(2,3).T.ravel().tolist()
['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f']
```